# Sorting Array in php?

Tags: php

i have an array like this

`[{"id"="1","rating"=>[{"rating"=>"1"}]},{"id"="2","rating"=>[{"rating"=>"2"}]},{"id"=>"3","rating"=>[{"rating"=>"3"}]}]`

here i need sort key based "rating" i need to expect output is

```
[{"id"="3","rating"=>[{"rating"=>"3"}]},{"id"="2","rating"=>[{"rating"=>"2"}]},{"id"=>"1","rating"=>[{"rating"=>"1"}]}]
```

can any one please guide how can i get this

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Just take a look at the manual, specifically: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: Also, all the `=` signs in your array should be `=>` signs.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep keys:

```
uasort($data, function($a, $b){ return ($a->rating > $b->rating); });
```

if you don't

```
usort($data, function($a, $b){ return ($a->rating > $b->rating); });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

aasort($your_array,"rating");
```

Source: [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

yuo can use php function usort.

You should provide your function to implement you sort critiria. For example

```
 function your_sort($a, $b)
 {
     return $b['rating'] - $a['rating'];
 }

 your_sort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care that the items of the array seems to be objects, and that the "rating" property is a string that should probably be converted into numeric.

```
function f_my_sort($a, $b) {
  if ($a->id==$b->id) return 0;
  return ( intval($a->rating) < intval($b->rating) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($my_array, "f_my_sort");
```